# dynamic table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m searching on how to create a dynamic table using JQuery/JS/HTML :
Here is the situation :
I have 3 MySQL Tables : `myClass, myStudent` and `myClassroom`
`myClass` : for the Classes.
`myStudent`: for Students.
`myClassroom`: link the student to a Class

I need to create a class and assign on it a list of students.
On the same page:
I have 2 panels:
first Panel is for Class elements
and
Second Panel is for Student belong to this class:
Inside the second Panel I have 2 parts  :

a. form to Enter a new student(with Name,Age... and a button).
b. table for student list , and this table it shows the entered student also at the right of it there is a button to be able to remove it if necessary.

I do have no problem with the first Panel, the class Name,.. is created in mysql table, However the in the second panel , i don't know how to start of creating a dynamic table after entering the new student on the first part  .

My question is how to :

1. To create dynamically the rows of the Table with a button on the right side(on click event to remove the Student from the appropriate class)

Hope you understand the situation , your help or support is really appreciated.

PS :I don t want to know how to append the row but also want to know how to manipulate the contents of `<td>` element. a specially the remove button on the right: which should take the Student Id (first column of the table) and execute a PHP script to remove it from MySQL.

Comment: try this  jquery datatables https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Thanks for ur prompt answer but this link is only for datatable with search and pagination. I don t see where I can apply my case

Comment: there are lot of plug and play extensions available for this https://www.datatables.net/extensions/index